# How to set specific width for a div while printing

Tags: html, css, printing, bootstrap-4

Suppose I have two div... `div1` and `div2`.

Now I set the width of `div1` 30% and `div2` 60%. And set a border between two div.

But `div1` takes 100% while I want to print.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arafat_rahman/z2v7hLfo/10/)  for your better underdstand

Anybody Help Please ?

Comment: Try using the css print media query. More info here: https://joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/

Comment: I can't find the width definitions in your CSS in your fiddle.  Is this complete?

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves...not complete yet.. I have updated the fiddel...please check

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle example is missing CSS for the print view, have you tried something like this:

```
@media print and (orientation: portrait) {

  @page {
    width: 210mm;
  }

  body {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 10pt;
    widows: 3;
    orphans: 3;
  }

  div {
    width: 60%;
  }

  div:first-of-type
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```